# Disable a TextBox in GridView and retain its value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, postback

I have a `TextBox` in a `GridView` which takes a user input. The problem is that it loses its value when I `click` on a `Button` placed in the `GridView` footer which adds an empty row to the `GridView`,How can I fix it?

Also, this happens only when I set its `Disabled` attribute to false in `RowDataBound` event. But if I set the `ReadOnly` attribute, everything works fine.

This is the `TextBox` in `GridView.Bound` to a DB data:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shift Code">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="txtingrid" ID="lblShiftCode" Text='<%# Eval("SHIFTCODE") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="50px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

this is what I do in the RowDataBound:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    lblShiftCode.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
}
```

Please help.:)

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0):

lblShiftCode.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: Sorry Brother, this isnt working as well. It still loses its value on postback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a post back on the button click, you will have to set the `UseSubmitBehavior` attribute to `"false"` on the button to retain values of the disabled controls.

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_usesubmitbehavior.asp)

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Refer to the link in my post, w3schools has en example for it.

Comment: I'm using a ImageButton, which unfortunately does not have that attribute. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just rebind the gridview after clicking the button. Suppose you are using `gridbind();` method to bind your gridview.So you have to call this method again after button click.

Comment: Thats the thing brother. I do rebind the Grid. The problem is there itself. coz when the shiftcode is bound to its corresponding column, it does not bind becoz that control is disabled.

Comment: why you are making textbox disable .What is your goal?

Comment: I just want to restrict the user from accessing(read/write) it.

Comment: who is entering value in that textbox? I think user is. if user is giving value to that text box then ehy are you restrict user from accessing it! Make your question more clear so that other can help you.